# Why my spring Application keep on opening a new connection to cloud atlas mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

These are the logs that i am getting repeatedly after **application Started**

```
2020-01-22T12:55:34,811 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56499adc55f60198441', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:429, serverValue:273700}] to x:27017
2020-01-22T12:55:34,856 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56499adc55f60198441', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:428, serverValue:275417}] to x:27017
2020-01-22T12:55:35,168 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56499adc55f60198441', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=x:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 2]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=181132909, setName='x-0', canonicalAddress=x:27017, hosts=[x:27017, x:27017, x:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='x:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[Tag{name='region', value='AP_SOUTH_1'}, Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}]}, electionId=7fffffff000000000000003e, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Wed Jan 22 12:55:30 IST 2020, lastUpdateTimeNanos=180151204451076}
2020-01-22T12:55:29,659 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56499adc55f60198441', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:424, serverValue:276311}] to x:27017
2020-01-22T12:55:30,054 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56199adc55f60198440', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:425, serverValue:273700}] to x:27017
2020-01-22T12:55:33,603 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56199adc55f60198440', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:426, serverValue:278143}] to x:27017
2020-01-22T12:55:34,663 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56199adc55f60198440', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:427, serverValue:275417}] to x:27017
2020-01-22T12:55:34,742 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56199adc55f60198440', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=x:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 2]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=133861489, setName='x-0', canonicalAddress=x:27017, hosts=[x:27017, x:27017, x:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='x:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='AP_SOUTH_1'}]}, electionId=7fffffff000000000000003e, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Wed Jan 22 12:55:30 IST 2020, lastUpdateTimeNanos=180150777860085}
2020-01-22T12:55:34,811 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56499adc55f60198441', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:429, serverValue:273700}] to x:27017
2020-01-22T12:55:34,856 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e27f56499adc55f60198441', description='null'}-x:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:428, serverValue:275417}] to x:27017
```

The cluster is M0 from cloud mongo atlas.
Whenever we whitelist some ip, the connections spikes above 100 which is the max. 
The connections drop once we remove that IP from the whitelist.
The strange part is even if we are not making any connections through the web-server on that I.P., the connections spike up.

Is is something related to monitor thread trying to reconnect even thought it gets connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar issue before, where the connections spiked even if we just whitelisted an IP. It was a strange issue, because we didnt make any connection from that whitelisted IP still the connection spiked.

But the solution was pretty strange, we **restarted** one of the developers system.
What we could suspect was, he had previously had many connection through, NoSQL Booster, terminal or through the local debug deployments itself.These connections didn't close by themselves and came up whenever his laptop connected to any whitelisted IP.

Pretty simple solution to the weird situation. Maybe you can try restarting the system.